# Spring security filter taking precendence over J2EE filter while calling REst API from SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, filter

I have 2 application say - 
Platform - Which is pure spring MVC.

COM - Which is spring boot application.

Platform take's care of authentication and authorization.

I have 2 filters in Platform -

1- For RestAPI authentication (Name - APISeqFilter)

2- For validating user input for login (ValidationFilter)

In COM I have java configuration for Filter Registration as below - (Note -  not web.xml)

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean COMAPISecurityFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(APISeqFilter());
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("product", "com");
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/com/rest/v1/*");
    registrationBean.setName("comAPISecurityFilter");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

XML file which is imported in COM like  -

```
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:platform-security-authentication.xml" })
```

having declaration for **ValidationFilter** which defined in Platform, which should be executed while login though UI(Not in case of REST API call)

```
<security:http auto-config="false" realm="My Realm" use-expressions="false">
<security:headers disabled="true"/>
   <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
   <!-- Form based Authentication -->
  <security:form-login login-page="/jsp/frameworklogin.jsp" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
      default-target-url="/jsp/index.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/jsp/frameworklogin.jsp?login_error=1"
      login-processing-url="/jsp/j_spring_security_check" always-use-default-target="true" />

  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />

  <security:custom-filter ref="HibernateSessionInViewFilter" position="FIRST" /> 
     <security:custom-filter ref="compositePreAuthFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
  <security:custom-filter ref="compositePreAuthFilterBefore" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
     <security:custom-filter ref="ssoAuthenticationProcessingFilter" after="CAS_FILTER" />
     <security:custom-filter ref="requestHeaderUserPatternPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
  <security:custom-filter ref="validationFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
     <security:custom-filter ref="SuiteSecurityFilter" position="LAST" />
     <security:custom-filter ref="logoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />

  <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" />

</security:http>
```

Both Platfrom and COM are deployed on same server -  with context root **/plat** and **/com** respectively

Now Problem is -

Expected  -  while calling COM Rest API ({HOST:PORT}/com/api/com/rest/v1/myAPI), APISeqFilter should be executed inside Platfrom.

Actual  - While executing API the call has been not reaching to **APISeqFilter**  instead it is reaching to **ValidationFilter**

**Note** -  While calling API which is created in Platform( say - > {HOST:PORT}/plat/api/plt/rest/v1/pltAPI) then APISeqFilter is called as expected.

What we have tried  - 
we have created WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as below, but call is not coming through configure method

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/*").authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Suspected area -

1 - Could be issue of different context root

2 - Web.xml corresponding configuration in COM application (absence of web.xml for declaring filter on Rest API URL patter)